# what is temp1: temp2= temp3 in python?

Tags: python

i'm beginner developer.
i don't know what it means.

```
fig: plt.Figure = plt.figure()
ax: plt.Axes = fig.add_axes((0, 0, 1, 1))
```

i want to know what means **:** in this code
i guessed that **plt.figure()**'s return will be arguments about **plt.Figure**
and return value about **plt.Figure** will pass to **fig**  in this sentence

but i'm not sure it is right flow.
i tried search in google but string ':' was dismissed..

thx for reading it. have a good day

Comment: A note on searching: if you google for [Python colon after variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+colon+after+variable), the very first hit explains it.

Comment: Seems like annotations, here's a reference:
https://realpython.com/lessons/annotations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`: plt.Figure` is a type annotation. For example:

```
x: int = 5
y: str = "hello"
```

So in your example, `fig` is a variable with type `plt.Figure`, and is assigned the returned value of `plt.figure()`.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i'm solving the problem. have a good day :)